# Django DetailView Not Getting Data From Model

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.8 and Python version 2.7.3

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obJr6zH0C2Q&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcTDEowl-b5nQlaDaD82r_s&index=1) tutorial as I'm still quite new to Django.

I was able to make the sample site from the tutorial and decided to make my own site using the functions from the tutorial. The site I am making is a simple search site for handymen. My issue is I cannot get DetailView to pull information from the database, I can however get it to pull the information when I put it as ListView and call the information in a for loop. I've gone over both the tutorial files and the files for the site I am making as this works perfectly on the tutorial site, hopefully I'm just skipping over something simple.

Here are my files:

**urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from search.models import People

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
            queryset=People.objects.all(),
            template_name="search.html")),

        url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(
            model=People,
            template_name="single.html")),

        url(r'^results/$', ListView.as_view(
            queryset=People.objects.all().order_by("-name")[:5],
            template_name="results.html")),         

)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    occupation = models.TextField()
    contact = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
```

**base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--header file-->
 <head>
    <title>Handyman Search</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" %}">

  </head>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

**search.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
<!--start of body-->
<div class="container" align="center" style="padding-top:180px">
<img src="{% static "images/hammer.jpeg" %}" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="container" style="padding-top:50px">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-push-1">
<form role="search" action="results">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." id="searchquery">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" href="results">Search</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
</form>
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!--container-->
</body>
<!-- end of body file -->
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

**results.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
<!--start of body-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-1" style="min-height:80px; min-width:90px">
<img src="{% static "images/hammer.jpeg" %}" class="img" width="100%" style="min-height:80px; min-width:80px">
</div>
  <div class="col-lg-10" style="padding-top:20px">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!--container-->

<!--results-->
<div class="container fluid" style="padding-top:80px">
<div class="row">
<div class="span6" style="float: none; margin: 0 auto;">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <!-- Default panel contents -->
  <div class="panel-heading">Results</div>


  <!-- List group -->
  <ul class="list-group">
    {% for post in object_list %}
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/search/{{post.id}}">{{ post.occupation }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--results end-->
{% endblock %}
```

**single.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
<!--start of body-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-1" style="min-height:80px; min-width:90px">
<img src="{% static "images/tux.jpeg" %}" class="img" width="100%" style="min-height:80px; min-width:80px">
</div>
  <div class="col-lg-10" style="padding-top:20px">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!--container-->

<!--results-->

<div class="container fluid" style="padding-top:80px">
<div class="row">
<div class="span6" style="float: none; margin: 0 auto;">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <!-- Default panel contents -->

  <div class="panel-heading">  {{ post.name }} </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>{{ post.occupation }} 
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></p>
<p style="text-align:center"><small><a href="#">{{ post.contact }}</a></small></p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--results end-->
{% endblock %}
```

When I searched for this particular issue I came across a lot of people posting up views.py, but I rewatched the tutorial and I never edited views.py yet it worked in the tutorial so I'm not 100% sure what went wrong.

Really appreciate any help or if you need anymore to look at please let me know.

Comment: Are you receiving an exception? Does the browser render the template?

Comment: First, I guess you forgot to add a trailing slash here `url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$'`. How do you actually try to pass the `pk` to the detailview or you manually type the url of the desired person page? Well, you can do everything in `urls.py`, however it might become quite complex one day...

Comment: Hi sorry, yes the browser displays the template and gives no error, the fields are just blank. I'll try the trailing slash hopefully that's all I am missing. I'm trying to pass the pk from the link on the results page. Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing anything called "post" to your detail template. Django will use the lower-case name of the model by default, so you can either change your template to use "people", or define `context_object_name` in the view/url to something more appropriate.

Comment: Oh my God thank you so much, this is exactly what the problem was. Thank you so much!